# What are the Cons of USA having a national ID system?

Tags: united-states, voting, immigration

I'm looking for a concise list of cons against promoting a National ID, and the implications that may have.

One of the more compelling arguments I've seen is that a "National ID" blurs the lines between state's rights and federal rights.  Specifically, such a project should be limited to defining requirements for inter-state interactions... and not focused on what documentation is required.

A second argument I've seen is that it contributes to the possibility of a Police State... though I don't see this argument clearly.  Assistance here is needed.

Comment: Want a totally cynical reason not to have National ID?  The government, politicians and the populace in general can then complain endlessly about illegal aliens without actually having an effective method to screen them out (aka National ID), so they can continue to work in agribusinesses, etc...

Answer (score 8):

- **Scope creep**

  This will likely be used for monitoring and surveillance of regular citizens

  They can be used to track and monitor all regular citizens, and past patterns suggest that could always becomes would

  - This definitely happened in the past (scope creep of Social Security #s)
  - NSA has collected domestic information despite being expressly prohibited by FISA
- Requires creation of the **database** of all Americans to deal with ID issuance

  - Databases like that tend to have bad data. Especially when Federal Government gets to run them (see no-fly list; or healthcare exchange debacles)

    Having an error in that database may have drastic negative consequences for an individual.
  - Having a database makes it both possible and tempting to use it to mine for data (see next couple of points for details)
- **Privacy violation** via tracking contradicting the spirit and letter of 4th/14th Amendment.

  Every access to check the ID would be tracked in the database, allowing tracking of your entire life far beyond what is possible now.
   (and not just for the kids with more social accounts than sense, who check in their every sneeze into FourTwitterBook)
- **3rd party privacy and tracking concerns**

  Having this data in the database would tempt everyone to try and get access to it.

  Depending on your personal ideological boogaboos, anyone from private companies to law enforcement to  advertisers would want to have access to that data and lobby extensively to do so.
- ACLU claims that it would increase discrimination

  ACLU (and separately, EFF) assumes that this would lead to minorities being unduly harrassed to provide the ID card.
- **Efficacy (lack thereof)**

  A national ID card system would not solve the problem that is inspiring it, according to ACLU.

  - Real bad actors have resources to obtain fake documents needed to get a real national ID

    This point has been made by both the progressive (ACLU), libertarian (Ron Paul) and conservative (Cato's Jim Harper) sides.
  - Many cases of bad actors (e.g. 9/11) had people who already held valid IDs and/or were in the country legally
- Another con raised by a commentor below:

  It's a database. You can **pay a low level data entry drone off** and insert any which data you want into it. Grand opportunities for fake identities, courtesy of social engineering coupled with by-design-single-point-of-failure.

***Sources***:

1. [ACLU: "5 Problems with National ID Cards"](https://www.aclu.org/5-problems-national-id-cards)
2. [ProCon summary of references of "Should the United States Implement a National Identification Card to Help Control Illegal Immigration?"](http://immigration.procon.org/view.answers.php?questionID=000854)

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any difference with these arguments at the national level vs state level?

Comment: @LamonteCristo - of course. Mostly, the usual national vs. state: e.g. states would exist without the system so people can move to opt out. The smaller scope makes for less tracking and less ability to violate privacy. It's easier to defeat politically (state referendum or reelection)

Comment: In fact some of the problems you cite would be solved by a national ID card (like stating clearly that the "John Smith" who is in the no-fly list is the one with ID #666 and not anyone with the same name).

Comment: @LamonteCristo An argument against would be the fact that individual states don't have the same resources to protect the information that the federal government does (and recent leaks of Federal employee information prove that not even they can keep Chinese hackers out of it).  It may also become cumbersome for people in multi-state areas, such as the New York Metropolitan Area, since sharing or combining data across state lines would be legally difficult, not to mention expand the scope of database breaches in any one of those states.

Comment: `Having an error in that database...` And we should not ignore that such errors give both false positives and false negatives. An erroneous (false, forged, whatever) record could grant entry to opportunities that would otherwise be questioned. E.g., the recent Paris terrorism was apparently helped by forged passport documents. How much could be possible with a falsified national ID database record?

Comment: @user2338816 - that is kinda covered in the last bullet but not explicitly

Comment: The last point is way, way off. If it was a real issue, you could pay a drone off to put $1.000.000 into your bank account (it is a database, too). Or the drone would to it to himself. Providing the appropiate authentication and audit measures you can minimize the risk of that happening, the same way banks do it.

Comment: Also, the "mine data point" depends of the ID database being used for things other than ID. An ID database would contain your personal data (name, DOB, maybe address), your ID number, maybe id info (fingerprints). It would not contain the list of films you dowloaded from Netflix, or your credit bank accounts. Yet opponents to national ID scores seem to imply that such a database would "automagically" link that all information to your ID.

Comment: @SJuan76 - do you have any idea how many databases use SSN as key?

Comment: But those are not the "national ID" database, so "having a national ID database" does not mean that it will be mined for data (as you explicitly mention in your answer). Current databases with SSN can already be mined, so a national ID does make little difference. In fact, in most cases full name and DOB and ZIP will be enough to uniquely identify almost everybody, so even SSNs are not needed for that (even if they make the process easier). Also, it is really not different if SSN is a key or just part of the data, using SSN as key is just bad DB design but does not affect mining at all.

Answer (score 4):

More a comment to user4012 answer than an answer, but the mistakes are so obvious that I cannot let them pass:

User4012 is confusing the national ID (a document that states that you are LamonteCristo, gives a few biometric mesures -picture, fingerprint, whatever- and an unique ID) with other databases (like police and intelligence records, the famous "do-not-fly" lists, and commercial activity databases). Guess what? They are not the same, and the "other databases" already exist.

An "error in the national ID" database means that your name or your address will be misspelled, and when you get your ID card you will see it. Errors in biometrics (fingerprints, etc.) may be harder to spot, but in any case it can be addressed by reclaming the issuer the correction of the data.

In fact, a national ID would help solve issues with some other databases that rely only in non-unique features to identify yourself. Someone like you is in the no-fly-list? Right now you are screwed. With a national ID, it would be easy to spot that the person in the no-fly-list is LamonteCristo with national ID 666, no LamonteCristo with national ID 69 which is you.

A more "nightmarish" (yet highly improbable) scenario is someone misstyping the data **in another database** (say, to serve an arrest warrant) and writting your national ID instead of someone's else, getting you arrested. Note that such a situation can already happen now with SSN/name/whatever is used to identify you in such a database (in fact, again, identification only by name is far more prone to errors). The most probable scenario is that you can point out that the warrant is Jane Doe with ID 69, which is obviously a mistake because you are LamotneCristo and you have the ID 69. Only an awfully designed system (say, only introducing the ID # in a warrant order) would take you slightly more to solve the administrative error.

And last but not least, the "tracking you databases" straw man. I mean, government and business like to know things about you, and you may uncomfortable with the idea. There are two points about that:

- The data you already provide to those databases is probably more than enough to cross-reference you.
- Business want to protect your data, not because they care about your feelings but because they need it for your business. If Netflix sells the data of which films you like to see and how much you pay for it, any competitor may be more efficient at mining and give you a better deal or a selection of films that you enjoy more.

In any case, a national ID (in the case that you provided it to those sites) would only be a help to a process that is already possible. If you really do not want business and government sharing your data, the answer is voting for a party that supports legislation banning the data cession.

Oh, and the "straw man" of terrorism. Well, user4012 seems to think that faking modern documents with modern security features is easy (maybe he has more experience at it than I do), but even accepting such a "truth" it is not an argument against national IDs (it could one less argument in favor of them).